# Clustered Index creation for large table

Tags: sybase, clustered-index

i have a table in sybase db , having >33 million records. There is an already existing clustered index on the table and I want to add a new column in table as well as index. But with these many records if i drop the index and create a new one with newly added column the process or index creation keeps on running for hours. Is there any way we can make it fast?

Comment: Add more engines? Use a Non-clustered index for the new column? Increase the number of worker procs?  Without knowing a little more about how things are setup and configured it's really hard to give you any real advice.  What Sybase Database are you running (ASE, IQ, SQL anywhere?) What version? which OS? What kind of storage environment? Clustered? Partitioned? How wide is the table..  33 million is not a huge number, unless your tables are really wide.  Have you done any reorgs on the table, or analysis of empty/split pages?

Comment: Remember we don't know anything about your environment, so give as much detail as you possibly can.